# Sybase optimizer creates a cursor for a DELETE query which then fails

Tags: sybase

We are executing the following query using embedded SQL in C:

`DELETE archive_table FROM archive_table arc, #arc_chunk loc WHERE arc.col = loc.col`

Sybase's response is:

> The DELETE WHERE CURRENT OF to the
>   cursor 'C42' failed because the cursor
>   is on a join.

The query is bewing constructed as a C string and then executed using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE in embedded SQL.

Is there a way to perform this DELETE without the Sybase optimizer creating a cursor (which fails) to execute it?

Answer (score 0):

When using the delete target table in a from clause don't put an alias on it.

```
  DELETE archive_table 
  FROM archive_table, #arc_chunk loc 
  WHERE archive_table.col = loc.col
```

[EDIT]

Another possibility is to remove the need for a join and fold it all into the where clause.

```
DELETE archive_table 
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM #arc_chunk loc WHERE archive_table.col = loc.col )
```

I am assuming that 'col' is the unique key for the row.

Comment: Nope... same problem. Except the cursor has now changed to 'C63172' :-(